# How to resolve the Error: Cannot find module './img1.jpg'

Tags: reactjs

[image for location](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OJGhj.png) 
I am trying to import an image from a fake database. Every other component works fine except for the image I am using   src={require(img)}  to insert the image

code for the inserting the image

```
const baseUrl = "./";
        const {el}=props;
        const img =baseUrl+el.img
        return( 
          
        <div className="card">
       <div className="imgBx">
       
        <img src={require(img)} alt=""/>
       </div>
```

Database
const products=[{

```
name:"PRODUCT1",
price:500,
rating:3,
img:"img1.jpg"
},
```

]
export  function Productss() {
return products
}

```
            <div className="body">
          <div className="container">
         { this.state.productsdetails.map(el=>(
              <Product
             el={el}
              />
```

Answer (score 0):

`require` arguments should be statically known and therefore cannot be variables, so you can't do `require(img)`.

I assume the image is stored on your local machine? I am not entirely sure what you mean by "fake database", and also your URL begins with a dot, so it's a fair assumption. If so, just ditch the `require` and do `<img src={img}/>`, this should work.

If it doesn't, you'd have to provide more information on where the image is stored.